# How to create a JQuery Filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a small web app, and I am having some trouble with this code that I have written. I need to do is: 
The form will accept input, such as name, age, and address and will add it to the list of data. It will check if a name already exists in the list. 
    If it does, trigger an update instead of adding to the list.

1. Add JQuery CDN script in the index.html (DONE)
2. Specify the document ready function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded(HALF DONE)
3. Add an event on the submit button to add or update an object in the list. Be sure to use PreventDefault to prevent the page refreshing
   on the form submit.
4. Add an event on the dropdown so when a name is selected from the list, the object's details are displayed in the form.
5. Add an event to the anchor within the list items so when a name is clicked, the object's details are displayed in the form.
6. Add an event on the clear button to clear the form data.

   Here is my code:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

     $("submit").click(function(event) {

       event.preventDefault();

     });

     var data = [{
       "name": "Bob",
       "age": 35,
       "address": {
         "street": "6565 Sunset Blvd",
         "zip": "90028",
         "city": "Los Angeles"
       }
     }, {
       "name": "Angela",
       "age": 25,
       "address": {
         "street": "1234 Tropicana blvd",
         "zip": "89100",
         "city": "Las Vegas"
       }
     }, {
       "name": "Carol",
       "age": 52,
       "address": {
         "street": "4232 Melrose ave",
         "zip": "90029",
         "city": "Los Angeles"
       }
     }, {
       "name": "Jack",
       "age": 63,
       "address": {
         "street": "1344 First Street",
         "zip": "90105",
         "city": "Las Vegas"
       }
     }, {
       "name": "Celine",
       "age": 21,
       "address": {
         "street": "1344 First Street",
         "zip": "10003",
         "city": "New York"
       }
     }, {
       "name": "Luke",
       "age": 74,
       "address": {
         "street": "1344 first street",
         "zip": "10105",
         "city": "Bronx"
       }
     }, {
       "name": "Martin",
       "age": 55,
       "address": {
         "street": "1344 first street",
         "zip": "10108",
         "city": "Bronx"
       }
     }];
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="loader" style="display:none;">
     <img class="ajax-loader" src="https://core.trac.wordpress.org/raw-attachment/ticket/21456/wpspin_light.gif" />
   </div>
   <div id="ajaxresults"></div>
   <div id="msg">Please select a filter</div>
   <select id="filter">
               <option value="">Choose a filter</option>
                   <option value="name">Name</option>
                   <option value="age">age</option>
                   <option value="address">Address</option>
           </select>

   <select id="filtercss">
               <option value="">Choose a style</option>
                   <option value="wb">with cell border</option>
                   <option value="nb">no cell border</option>
           </select>

   <table id="tbl" style="border-style:solid;border-size:1px;">
   </table>
   ```

Comment: Which part of the code is causing an error or a problem?

Comment: Javascript part

Comment: "_JavaScript part_", no I mean which line in the block of code is causing an error? We cannot make the code for you, if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Do you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/k1e359mx/1/

Comment: Can you check out the javascript part, because I think I am getting an syntax error

Comment: @FemiOladeji Similar to do that, but is it possible to add a drop box menu of the "Age", "Name", and "Address".When they choose name, it will show up the names only .

Comment: For age and name yes. But that of address is a little fuzzy considering the fact that it's also a nested object

Comment: @FemiOladeji can you please show me?

Comment: @FemiOladeji something like that in my updated question

Comment: Oh I see, check this out then https://jsfiddle.net/k1e359mx/2/